# Textmate Hide/Show Comments

Tags: textmate

Is there any way with TextMate to hide comments when editing code?  Sometimes I want to see my code with the full comments and other times just want to see the code itself with all comments hidden.  I was hoping there would be a way to toggle the display of comments, but haven't been able to find anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is something you will need to edit on a language by language basis, but it is very doable. Inside of `Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Edit Languages` you will find the language definition that TextMate uses to highlight that particular syntax. Inside of the syntax definition you will find `foldingStartMarker` and `foldingStopMarker`.

You can add comment syntax to those to allow the folding off comments themselves. It might be pretty tricky for single line comments, but multiline comments, that have both a clear and unique start and stop syntax, should work fine.

For PHP, for example, we are going to want to add `\/\*` to the start syntax, and `\*\/` to the end syntax. You will need to reload the bundle for these changes to take effect (or restart TM).